# Manually Adding Toolbox to Matlab R2013b

Tags: matlab, path, toolbox

I am working with OS X version 10.9.4 and using Matlab R2013b. I have recently downloaded a toolbox file and it saved as a folder on my desktop. It contains a bunch of .m files, which I'm not really sure how to add into my Matlab. I've read online and watched a few tutorials that all mention that I need to set the path to Matlab, but I can't seem to get it to work for me. I'm very new to Matlab and have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days, so my apologies if this is a very simple question to be asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. When a function is called in Matlab, it will look in all the directories contained within the path to find it. You can bring up the path by typing in the command "path".

Presumably, you want to add a new location for Matlab to look. This can be done via the addpath command. Addpath accepts both relative and absolute addresses. For example the command

```
addpath('C:\My_Matlab_Functions')
```

will enable you to access functions & files within the folder My_Matlab_Functions.

Relative directories are taken relative to the file which calls addpath. For example if I am running a function within C:\users\user_name\My_Documents\Matlab, calling

```
addpath('Tools')
```

will enable you to access all of the files within C:\users\user_name\My_Documents\Matlab\Tools. You can also go up directories via '..'. For example, if I am running a function within C:\users\user_name\My_Documents\Matlab\Project1, the command

```
addpath('..\Tools')
```

Accesses the same tools folder as before.

I have tried these examples on Windows, but I presume they work the same on a Mac. Hope this helps.

Alternatively, you may be able to add your file(s) directly into Matlab's built in toolbox. I don't know whether Matlab automatically searches for new folders here, but it may be worth a shot.